# Displaying a layers CRS in a dockpane using ArcGIS Pro SDK .NET

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am currently building up a dock pane where a user can add a layer (using a button within the dock pane). And the layer's CRS is to be displayed in a text box below (this is for a later part of functionality).

I am struggling to find any documentation surrounding extracting a layer's CRS. I know there are built in functionality to be able to do this easily (right clicking on the layer), but I would like to display it in a text box, for example, CRS: British National Grid (not too bothered on the formatting).

My code below would then add the layer selected by the user from a GDB and display it on the map. Does anyone know how to then extract the CRS from it?

This is where I am at right now:

```
 public async void SelectLayersBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
           // first open the Item Dialog
           
            OpenItemDialog AOIFilter = new OpenItemDialog
            {
                Title = "Add Layers to Model",
                InitialLocation = @"C:\Data",
                Filter = "Shapefiles (*.shp)|*.shp",
                MultiSelect = true,
            };

            bool? ok = AOIFilter.ShowDialog();

            if (ok == true)
            {
                // Provide list of all items, then load them to a map
                IEnumerable<Item> selectedAOI = (IEnumerable<Item>)AOIFilter.Items;
                List<string> queryResultsforUI = new List<string>();

                foreach (Item selectedItem in selectedAOI)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       // trim path of url to what arc wants

                        string _url = selectedItem.ToString();
                        string url = _url.Substring(_url.IndexOf('@') + 1).Trim('>');

                        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                        await QueuedTask.Run(() => LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer(uri, MapView.Active.Map));

                    }

                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Dialogs.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error");
                    }             
                }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a little while to get back and actually answer my own question! I found out the issue quite soon after writing this.

You need to take the Selected Item from the geodatabase, then actually connect to the GDB with the path. After that, cast it as a FeatureClass, then all of the information needed will then be available as parameters of the FeatureClass Type.

```
using (Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase(new DatabaseConnectionFile(new Uri(@GeodatabasePath))))
                    {
                        // Open a featureClass (within a feature dataset or outside a feature dataset).
                        try
                        {
                            using (FeatureClass featureClass = geodatabase.OpenDataset<FeatureClass>(LayerName))
                            {
                                // retrieve the class definition of the point feature class
                                string classDefinition = featureClass.GetDefinition().GetSpatialReference().Name.ToString();
                            } 
                         }
                     }
```